# I want a clever algorithm for indexing a file directory...pointers?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, hash

I have a directory of music on Ubuntu (.mp3, .wav, etc) files. This directory can have as many sub directories as it needs, no limits. I want to be able to make a music library out of it - that is, return list of songs based on filters of:

1) membership to playlist
2) artist name
3) string search
4) name of song
etc, etc

However, if file names are changed, moved, or even added to my Music directory, I need to be able to reflect this is in my music organization engine - quickly!

I originally thought to just monitor my directory with pyinotify, incron, or inotify. Unfortunately my directory is a Samba share and so monitoring file events [failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795847/notifier-on-linux-filesystem-for-samba-share). So my next guess was to simply recursively search the directory in python, and populate a SQL database. Then when updating, I would just look to see if anything has changed (scanning each subfolder to see if each song's name is in the database already, and if not adding it), and make UPDATEs accordingly. Unfortunately, this seems to be a terrible `O(n^2)` implementation - awful for a multi-terabyte music collection.

A slightly better one might involve creating a tree structure in SQL, thus narrowing the possible candidates to search for a match at any given subfolder step to the size of that subfolder. Still seems inelegant.

What design paradigms/packages can I use to help myself out? Obviously will involve lots of clever hash tables. I'm just looking for some pointers in the right direction for how to approach the problem. (Also I'm a complete junkie for optimization.)

Comment: Why would your original idea by O(n^2)?  Assuming the database had a O(log n) index on the song name (which should be easy to arrange) it should be O(n log n).

Comment: If you are so worried about complexity you could use a hash which is `O(n)` for `n` lookups/updates.

Comment: I second the hashing idea; the only problem is, how do you decide a unique key to hash with? I wouldn't go with any of the normal file attributes, cause those can change. Maybe make a key based on samples from within the file?

Comment: Your filters are not so clear. What if you have multiple memberships in a play list?

Comment: Well, an obvious key would be the path to the file (relative to the root directory), I'd think.

Comment: @andrewdski, how would be the best way to get an O(log n) index? I suppose a binary tree structure of the directories could do this?

Comment: @machine yearning, well I could go with the ID3 `title` tag since when users rename things in finder/windows explorer, this doesn't change

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: yeah but if you want to check for new files based on new mappings in your hash table, I'd not just do a check on one of these things or the other (file path or ID3 title) but rather both. You could either do a multiple-hash (2 or more) scheme to check for identity or collude both of these variables (combine them to make stronger) with a hash key generation algorithm. The trick is that you want to pick attributes that will never "collide" when hashed unless they have the same "stuff" (in this case both file path and ID3 title tag).

Comment: Yes, but no two files can have the same path, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard part of this is the scanning of the directory, just because it can be expensive.

But that's a cruel reality since you can't use inotify et al.

In your database, simply create a node type record:

```
create table node (
    nodeKey integer not null primary key,
    parentNode integer references node(nodeKey), // allow null for the root, or have root point to itself, whatever
    fullPathName varchar(2048),
    nodeName varchar(2048),
    nodeType varchar(1) // d = directory, f = file, or whatever else you want
)
```

That's your node structure.

You can use the full path column to quickly find anything by the absolute path.

When a file moves, simply recalculate the path.

Finally, scan you music files. In unix, you can do something like:

find . -type f | sort > sortedListOfFiles

Next, simply suck all of the path names out of the database.

select fullPathName from node where nodeType != 'd' order by fullPathName

Now you have two sorted list of files.

Run them through DIFF (or comm), and you'll have a list of deleted and new files. You won't have a list of "moved" files. If you want to do some heuristic where you compare new and old files and they have the same endings (i.e. ..../album/song) to try and detect "moves" vs new and old, then fine, no big deal. Worth a shot.

But diff will give you your differential in a heartbeat.

If you have zillions of files, then, sorry, this it going to take some time -- but you already know that when you lose the inotify capability. If you had that it would just be incremental maintenance.

When a file moves, it's trivial to find its new absolute path, because you can ask its parent for its path and simply append your name to it. After that, you're not crawling a tree or anything, unless you want to. Works both ways.

Addenda:

If you want to track actual name changes, you can get a little more information.

You can do this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -i | sort -n > sortedListOfFileWithInode
```

The -print0 and -0 are used to work with files with spaces in them. Quotes in the file names will wreck this however. You might be better off running the raw list through python and fstat to get the inode. Different things you can do here.

What this does is rather than just having names, you also get the inode of the file. The inode is the "real" file, a directory links names to inodes. This is how you can have multiple names (hard links) in a unix file system to a single file, all of the names point to the same inode.

When a file is renamed, the inode will remain the same. In unix, there's a single command used for renaming, and moving files, mv. When mv renames or moves the file, the inode stays the same AS LONG AS THE FILE IS ON THE SAME FILE SYSTEM.

So, using the inode as well as the file name will let you capture some more interesting information, like file moves.

It won't help if they delete the file and add a new file. But you WILL (likely) be able to tell that it happened, since it is unlikely that an old inode will be reused for the new inode.

So if you have a list of files (sorted by file name):

```
1234 song1.mp3
1235 song2.mp3
1236 song3.mp3
```

and someone removes and adds back song 2, you'll have something like

```
1234 song1.mp3
1237 song2.mp3
1236 song3.mp3
```

But if you do this:

```
mv song1.mp3 song4.mp3
```

You'll get:

```
1237 song2.mp3
1236 song3.mp3
1234 song4.mp3
```

The other caveat is that if you lose the drive and restore it from backup, likely all of the inodes will change, forcing effectively a rebuild of your index.

If you're real adventurous you can try playing with extended file system attributes and assign other interesting meta data to files. Haven't done much with that, but it's got possibilities as well, and there are likely unseen dangers, but...

Comment: thanks! the unix `find` command is lightning fast - much better than python. what do you mean by DIFF? I searched and couldn't find it in the MySQL docs

Comment: oh nvm. you meant the unix diff command (i think). the only problem this doesn't solve is that if files are renamed, the playlists table in the database won't be able to keep track of which paths belong to which playlist - I won't have a way to track them. Unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

my `aggregate_digup` program reads an extended sha1sum.txt format file produced by the [digup](https://idlebox.net/2009/digup/) program. this lets me locate a file based on its sha1sum. the digup program stores the mtime size hash and pathname in its output. by default it skips hashing a file if the mtime and size match. the index produced by my aggregate_digup is used by my modifed version of the open uri context menu gedit plugin allowing one to option click on `sha1:b7d67986e54f852de25e2d803472f31fb53184d5` and it'll list the copies of the file it knows about so you can pick one and open it.

how this relates to the problem is that there are two parts: one the playlists and two the files.

if we can assume that nothing the player does changes the files, then the hash and sizes of the files are constant. so we should be able to use the size and hash of a file as a unique identifier.

for example the key for the file mentioned: `222415:b7d67986e54f852de25e2d803472f31fb53184d5`

i've found that in practice this has no collisions in any natural collection.

(this does mean that the ID3 metadata which is appended or prepended to the mp3 data can't change unless you choose to skip that metadata while hashing)

so the playlist database would be something this:

```
files(file_key, hash, size, mtime, path, flag)
tracks(file_key, title, artist)
playlists(playlistid, index, file_key)
```

to update the files table:

```
import os
import stat
# add new files:
update files set flag=0
for path in filesystem:
    s=os.stat(path)
    if stat.S_ISREG(s.st_mode):
        fetch first row of select mtime, hash, size from files where path=path
        if row is not None:
            if s.st_mtime == mtime and s.st_size == size:
                update files set flag=1 where path=path
                continue
        hash=hash_file(path)
        file_key="%s:%s" % (int(s.st_mtime), hash)
        insert or update files set file_key=file_key, size=s.st_size, mtime=s.st_mtime, hash=hash, flag=1 where path=path
# remove non-existent files:
delete from files where flag=0
```

Comment: awesome idea you mentioned. any idea how I could return a hash of ONLY the music (audio) data and not the ID3 tags in python? Am I guaranteed that normal playing, renaming, and moving of files won't change non-ID3 data?

Comment: you'd have to locate the start and end of the ID3 metadata with a parser and skip over it when hashing. the location of the ID3 data depends on the version, iir, one version appears at the start of the file and the others appears at the end.; playing shouldn't change the file unless you have a badly written player. renaming and moving a file doesn't effect the contents of a file, only the filesystem metadata, unless its a badly written filesystem. tbh, i use commandline mplayer as my main player, i even sought out the rather simple pymp for playing music playlists.

Comment: the idea of skipping the ID3 metadata, i got from the mp3dup program which merely had the option to skip bytes at the start and end of the files.

Answer (score 2):

The reality is, this is a **hard** problem. You're starting from a disadvantage as well: Python and mySQL aren't the fastest tools to use for this purpose.

Even iTunes is complained about because of the time it takes to import libraries and index new files. Can you imagine the man hours that went into making iTunes as good as it is?

Your best bet is to look at the code of major open source music players such as

- Miro, http://www.getmiro.com/,
- Banshee, http://banshee.fm/, and
- Songbird, http://getsongbird.com/

And try an adapt their algorithms to your purpose and to Python idioms.

Comment: well I figured python wasn't, but I thought MySQL was just about the fastest you could get for a large DB on a local machine...

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re
```

your other code here that initially sets up a dictonary containing which files you already have in your library (I called the dictionary archived_music)

```
music_directory = '/home/username/music'
music_type = '\.mp3$|\.wav$|\.etc$'
found_files = os.popen('find %s -type f -mtime 1 2>/dev/null' % music_directory)
for file in found_files:
    directory, filename = os.path.split()
    if re.compile(music_type).search(filename):
        #found a music file, check if you already have it in the library
        if filename in archived_music:
            continue
        #if you have gotten to this point, the music was not found in the arcchived music directory, so now perform whatever processing you would like to do on the full path found in file.
```

You can use this code as a little function or whatever and call it on whatever time resolution you would like.  It will use the find command and find every newly created file within the last day.  It will then check whether it is of type music_type, if it is it will check the filename against whatever current database you have set up and you can continue processing from there.  This should be able to get your started for updating newly added music or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past, but ended up utilizing Amarok w/ MySQL. Amarok will create a mysql database for you and index all your files quite nicely - after that interfacing with the database should be relatively straightforward from python.

It was quite a time saver for me :)

HTH